Converting Html to vue 3 , some js is not working like swiper
My banner slider is working, but it only displays the background images and not the  tag or text that I added. The banner section is visible in the inspect elements but not displaying on the page.
What I've Done:
Installed Swiper: I've installed the Swiper plugin via npm and imported it into my Vue component.
Setup Swiper: Initialized Swiper in the mounted lifecycle hook.
Data Binding: Passed dynamic data to the Swiper slides using Vue's data binding.
Issues:
Visible in DOM: The banner section is rendered in the DOM and visible in the inspect elements, but the text and additional  tags are not displayed.
Only Background Images: Only the background images are displayed in the slider, none of the text or buttons are visible.
My Template Code:
Here is my template code:
<template>
  <div class="swiper-container" ref="swiperContainer">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div v-for="slide in slides" :key="slide.title" class="swiper-slide" :style="slide.style">
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>{{ slide.title }}</h2>
          <p>{{ slide.subtitle }}</p>
          <a :href="slide.button.link">{{ slide.button.text }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <button class="swiper-button-next"></button>
    <button class="swiper-button-prev"></button>
  </div>
</template>

Here is my script code:
import Swiper from "swiper";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      swiperOptions: {
        slidesPerView: 1,
        autoplay: {
          delay: 8000,
          disableOnInteraction: false,
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        // Add more Swiper options as needed
      },
      slides: [
        {
          style: {
            backgroundImage: `url(${require("@/assets/images/demos/demo1/sliders/slide-1.jpg")})`,
            backgroundColor: "#ebeef2",
          },
          subtitle: 'Custom Men’s',
          title: "RUNNING SHOES",
          button: {
            text: "SHOP NOW",
            link: "shop-list.html",
          },
          animationOptions: {
            subtitle: { name: "fadeInRightShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".2s" },
            title: { name: "fadeInRightShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".4s" },
            text: { name: "fadeInRightShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".6s" },
            button: { name: "fadeInRightShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".8s" },
          },
        },
        {
          style: {
            backgroundImage: `url(${require("@/assets/images/demos/demo1/sliders/slide-2.jpg")})`,
            backgroundColor: "#ebeef2",
          },
          subtitle: 'Mountain-Climbing',
          title: "Hot & Packback",
          button: {
            text: "SHOP NOW",
            link: "shop-banner-sidebar.html",
          },
          animationOptions: {
            subtitle: { name: "fadeInUpShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".2s" },
            title: { name: "fadeInUpShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".4s" },
            text: { name: "fadeInUpShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".8s" },
            button: { name: "fadeInUpShorter", duration: "1s", delay: "1s" },
          },
        },
        {
          style: {
            backgroundImage: `url(${require("@/assets/images/demos/demo1/sliders/slide-3.jpg")})`,
            backgroundColor: "#f0f1f2",
          },
          subtitle: "Top weekly Seller",
          title: "Trending Collection",
          button: {
            text: "SHOP NOW",
            link: "shop-list.html",
          },
          animationOptions: {
            subtitle: { name: "fadeInLeftShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".4s" },
            title: { name: "fadeInLeftShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".2s" },
            text: { name: "fadeInLeftShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".8s" },
            button: { name: "fadeInLeftShorter", duration: "1s", delay: ".6s" },
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // Initialize Swiper
    this.swiper = new Swiper(this.$refs.swiperContainer, this.swiperOptions);
  },
  destroyed() {
    // Destroy Swiper instance when component is destroyed
    if (this.swiper) {
      this.swiper.destroy();
    }
  },
};




Do not post pictures of code. 2. there's no evidence of vue in your code, it's only jqueeeeery


I do not see any zoom now. Also url(${require is probably not the way to go with Vite. Otherwise the syntax does not look too bad, assuming the right version is used and it is compatible with Options API (probably is).
